# Asterisk AMI events sometimes missing

Tags: asterisk, asteriskami

I have a Python service which connects to Asterisk via AMI and listens for events to detect when a call has begun.

This seems to work on most of the Asterisk servers I connect to.  However, on a few of our servers we just don't see any of the AMI events (e.g. `Newstate`) when the call happens, though we do later see the `Cdr` event once the call has completed.

I've confirmed that this isn't specific to the library we're using to connect to AMI ([py-Asterisk](https://pypi.org/project/py-Asterisk/)), because I see exactly the same thing when I connect manually, e.g.

```
$ openssl s_client -connect my-asterisk-server:5039
...
Asterisk Call Manager/2.10.3
Action: Login
Username: manager
Secret: ThisIsWhereITypedTheActualPassword

Response: Success
Message: Authentication accepted

Event: FullyBooted
Privilege: system,all
Status: Fully Booted

Action: Events
EventMask: on

Response: Success
Events: on
```

In the above block, I manually connected to AMI, logged in as the same administrator my Python code is using, and ensured that all events are turned on (though my asterisk config should already be displaying all events I care about by default).

After this point what I see on some of my Asterisk servers is a series of expected events like `Newstate`, followed by an eventual `Cdr` event.  On other servers, I see **only** the `Cdr` event, with nothing proceeding it.  This is completely consistened within each server, meaning a server either always sends all of the expected events or it never does.

I've checked the versions of asterisk, the `manager.conf` config file, the `extensions.conf` dialplan, the asterisk console in verbose mode (i.e. connecting via `asterisk -vvvr` to the running process), and just generally comparing my config files to my actually-working Asterisk servers.

I'm stumped as to what could be causing this, or even what to try next.  If it matters, here's what my `manager.conf` looks like:

```
[general]
tlsenable=yes
tlsbindaddr=10.0.0.123:5039
tlscertfile=/etc/pki/asterisk/ami.crt
tlsprivatekey=/etc/pki/asterisk/ami.key

[admin]
secret=TheActualPasswordIsOnThisLine
read=system,call,log,verbose,command,agent,user,originate,cdr
write=system,call,log,verbose,command,agent,user,originate,cdr
```

EDIT: After some further digging, it seems that the **only** events which are showing up are `Cdr` events, so even things like peer registration events don't show up.  I've also confirmed that all of my Asterisk 13.19.0-1 servers are exhibiting this behavior, and the only working servers are running much older versions of Asterisk.

The weird thing is that calls do come through successfully, so the problem is not that I'm missing some necessary module.  (Or maybe I am?  Is there some "make events show up in AMI" module that I need to ensure is loaded?)

FURTHER EDIT: I was able to turn on CEL events (Channel Event Logging), and those events show up, but this is a different set of events than the standard `Newchannel`/`Newstate`/etc I'm looking for.  In theory I could rewrite a large portion of my service to use the CEL events, but ideally I'd just turn on the standard `Newstate`/`Newchannel`/`Hangup` events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the issue is that I was missing

```
enabled=yes
```

in my `manager.conf`.  Hopefully this will be helpful to someone in the future: even if you're able to connect to AMI, log into AMI, receive some events from AMI, and send commands to AMI and get responses back, it might not be `enabled`, and this will suppress most of the core events like `Newchannel`, `Newstate`, etc.

One clue was that running `manager show settings` in the asterisk console returned this:

```
Global Settings:
----------------
  Manager (AMI)           No
  ...
```

which is apparently how it indicates that it's not enabled.